# Add Active Class to parent element Based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I Need to assign a class "active" to a menu navigation but the class active should be assigned to the "li" element and not the link "a" element. How can I modify the code below to achieve this  result? There is also another issue and that is that all the elements gets assigned with the active class because my links change only the last few letters..

```
<nav>
    <ul class="tabbable">
        <li class="active"><a href="/portal.php?mode=articles&block=mylink1">my link</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="/portal.php?mode=articles&block=mylink2">my link</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="/portal.php?mode=articles&block=mylink3">my link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

my JS:

```
<script>
head.ready(function () {
  $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
head.ready(function () {
  $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the speedy reply! it works but there is one problem. all the elements are marked as active. :-/ I updated the first post with the links example.

Comment: You should correct choose a. element here: $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]')

Comment: I tried this but it does not work: $('nav a[href^="&block=' + location.pathname.split("&block=")[1] + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve. Something like this work: $('nav a[href="' +location.pathname + location.search +'"]') - it select only one 'a' element

Comment: Brialliant! This works: $('nav a[href="' +location.pathname + location.search +'"]')  you saved my day! I was on this for a long time!